# CSS optimisation recommendations

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project of mine and it is my first time doing PSD to HTML/CSS. 
I put my work so far online, if I could get advices on what I'm doing wrong (I don't have sprites yet but I will), that would be great.

The link is there REDACTED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do

▸
Leverage browser caching
[Score: 8/100]

▸Optimize images
[Score: 22/100]

▸Enable compression

also there is a

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 
})(jQuery);
```

also this is an issue on resizing the browser

[image]

**Note:** dont use `!important` unless you really need to but you have uses important too much

also its seems like you are not resting browser default css ...try http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: what's causing this: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

})(jQuery); ??

Comment: and browser caching is somethnig that's done server side, no ?

Comment: (!important are gone)
re the resizing issue, I saw that on Dreamweaver but don't quite understand what's doing it, can you point to whatever I have to do ?!

Comment: yup it is but i suggest to do this it will increase site speed since all script and css needs to be loaded once

Comment: I'll leave that to a programmer I think :) (This isn't the actual server anyways)

Comment: its seems like you are not resting browser default css ...try http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thank you very much. (I added it so it should be fixed now!)

Comment: @CharlieAllombert yours very welcome ...:)